# Visual Studio: How to dock multiple buttons at bottom

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image]

the buttons inside the greyed bottom stay at the bottom even when the form is resized.. is this something from the toolbox?

Comment: Don’t you want them to stay at the bottom when the form is resized? Could you maybe show an example of what happens when you resize the form?

Comment: woops i meant them to float at the bottom.. it's from this tutorial http://youtu.be/_VZ0R0jrW1k?t=2m47s

Comment: What does that mean? What happens when the form is resized, and what do you want to happen instead?